# Add a sudoer non-interactively from command line

Tags: linux, centos, docker, sudo, sudoers

(On Centos through Docker)

I know that I can add a sudoer using `visudo`.  Is there a way to add a user to the sudoer list straight from the command line, so I don't have to do it interactively?

I'm asking because I'm trying to provision my Docker centos container which doesn't play with interactivity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `cat` to append text to the end of `/etc/sudoers`.  First, make a backup copy of your `/etc/sudoers` file.  Then:

```
cat >> /etc/sudoers
...type one or more lines here...
[control-D]
```

Make absolutely sure to use *two* greater-than characters (`>>`) and not just one, or else you will overwrite the entire contents of your file.

Comment: how is this "non-interactively"? and why is this answer accepted?

Comment: The OP asked for a way to do it from the command line, without using an editor such as `visudo`. I believe they meant "interactive" in the sense of using an editor; thus, this is "non-interactive" because this approach does not require an editor. (Obviously, a person will still have to type the user names _somehow_, so there is no getting around that part.) As for why it was accepted, well, I guess it must have addressed the OP's question well enough that they were satisfied.

Comment: ok, to me interactive means anything requiring live user-input. Editor or command line. Semantics I guess. thanks.

Comment: What you say makes sense too – the expression is ambiguous enough that people usually need to say something more to clarify their intentions. I took a guess, but could easily have been wrong.  In practical terms, what I wrote above could be written into a script file (e.g., an sh script); what TemporalWolf wrote _is_ what goes into a script file. And honestly, considering that the OP's question was specifically about Docker, I think TemporalWolf's answer might actually be a better one.

Comment: @AlexanderMills You're right that this is interactive, but it can easily be tweaked to become non-interactive.

Answer (score 19):

I had a similar issue trying to get my docker container to allow jenkins scripts to use sudo commands without prompting for a password.

This was solved via the Dockerfile:

```
RUN echo "jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
```

Answer (score 2):

To be able to do that, you should make sure you have the following line in your `sudoers` file:

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

You can customize the above line to change the permissions just as though `%sudo` was a user.
That line will allow any users in the `sudo` group to use `sudo`.

Now to allow `<username>` to use `sudo`, you can just do `usermod -a -G sudo <username>` as root, which adds `<username>` to the `sudo` group.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I setup a non-root user with the base image of `ubuntu:18.04`:

```
RUN \
    groupadd -g 999 foo && useradd -u 999 -g foo -G sudo -m -s /bin/bash foo && \
    sed -i /etc/sudoers -re 's/^%sudo.*/%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL/g' && \
    sed -i /etc/sudoers -re 's/^root.*/root ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL/g' && \
    sed -i /etc/sudoers -re 's/^#includedir.*/## **Removed the include directive** ##"/g' && \
    echo "foo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers && \
    echo "Customized the sudoers file for passwordless access to the foo user!" && \
    echo "foo user:";  su - foo -c id
```

What happens with the above code:

- The user and group `foo` is created.
- The user `foo` is added to the both the `foo` and `sudo` group.
- The `uid` and `gid` is set to the value of `999`.
- The home directory is set to `/home/foo`.
- The shell is set to `/bin/bash`.
- The `sed` command does inline updates to the `/etc/sudoers` file to allow `foo` and `root` users passwordless access to the `sudo` group.
- The `sed` command disables the `#includedir` directive that would allow any files in subdirectories to override these inline updates.

Answer (score 2):

A more modern method, given the age of this post, is to place a per-user file in `/etc/sudoers.d/` or the appropriate similar location for whatever OS is at reference.  So long as your `sudoers` file contains a line like:

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Then a script like this can be used to create a per-user sudoers file for any valid username:

```
#/usr/bin/env bash

SUDOERS_DIR='/etc/sudoers.d/'

if [ $# -eq 1 ]
then
    printf '%s ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL\n' "$1" > "$SUDOERS_DIR$1" && \
        chmod 600 "$SUDOERS_DIR$1"
else
    printf 'usage: $0 (username)\n'
    printf '(username) will be given sudo privileges\n'
    exit 1
fi
```

With this, an unprivileged user:

```
/home/jim> sudo -i
Password:
jim is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

can easily be given sudo access on a per-user basis:

```
/root# ./addsudo.sh 
usage: $0 (username)
(username) will be given sudo privileges
/root# ./addsudo.sh jim
/root# ls -l /etc/sudoers.d/
total 1
-rw-------  1 root  wheel  22 Oct  4 15:35 jim
/root# cat /etc/sudoers.d/jim
jim ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

And voila:

```
/home/jim> sudo -i
Password:
/root#
```

When the time comes to revoke the `sudo` privileges, simply `rm` the file for that user:

```
# rm /etc/sudoers.d/jim
```

Answer (score 1):

A common arrangement for appending to files which require privileged access is to use `tee`.  Its primary purpose, of course, is to write to two places, but you can discard one of them and use the side effect that `sudo tee -a` gives you privileged append.

So, something like

```
printf 'you ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL\n' | sudo tee -a /etc/sudoers >/dev/null
```

I will concur with the comments to add the user to the `sudoers` group instead to solve this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by enabling the 'wheel' group in sudoers, and after you only need to add users to that group. Avoids convoluting the sudoers file.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment of the user creation, you can specify the user **someone** belongs to the **sudo** group in this way:

```
useradd --groups sudo someone
```

If it is an already existent user, you can add it to a new group in this way:

```
gpasswd --add someone sudo
```

See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/799439/246605) if you want to know why I prefer `gpasswd` to `usermod`.